# how to change my web site's elements style dynamicly

Tags: php

In index.php file I first check if `$_SESSION['user']` is set it would not show the login form and if not, the login form should be shown.

Here is my login form style

```
<style>
#login_form{visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

And my PHP script is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
dont show the login form;
else
show the login form;
?>
```

and the question is: how can I change the `#login_form` style to `visible`?

Comment: Terry ? can you help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339070/how-to-prevent-users-having-access-to-a-particular-directory

Comment: Hard to help when you don't approve answers on your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Why not adding an inline style (perhaps a class would be even better) when the user is logged in?

```
<form style="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { echo 'visibility: hidden;';}?>">
    <!-- Rest of the form -->
</form>
```

Or even better, print the form only when is logged in (so visitors can't force the browser to display the form):

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
    <form>
        <!-- Rest of the form -->
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: <script>
      document.getElementById("login_form").style.visibility="<?php      if($login) echo('visible');else echo( 'hidden');?>;"
    </script>

Comment: It's not JS code that I am writing... it's written in PHP and HTML.

Comment: @Terry - Strictly speaking your not actually adding a class, you're adding an inline-style to the form-element (when logged-in)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I think I forgot to change the code or the description when I was editing...

Comment: @Terry - I just noticed it and I wanted you to be notified :-)

Comment: @Terry ? can you help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339070/how-to-prevent-users-having-access-to-a-particular-directory

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS class:

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then apply it when your user is already logged in:

```
<form class="<?=isset($_SESSION['user']) ? 'invisible' : ''?>">
```

Comment: I would go for this solution because then you don't have to involve any js to achieve what op wants to do! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have it directly in the `div` that holds the form, like this:

```
<div style="<?if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){echo 'display:block'}else{echo 'display:none'}?>">
...Form code
</div>
```