# how to prevent users having access to a particular directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory named "includes" containing information about my database and some other important files that users should not access. I want to use an `.htaccess` file to redirect requests that begin with "/includes" to `errors/403.html`. This is my code but it does not work. What's the problem?!

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^/includes/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$    /errors/403.html    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Put the directory outside of your web root.

Comment: sorry im asking, is the code above wrong?!

Comment: Please define "does not work". What happens? Do you get errors?

Answer (score 0):

If your config files are php, you can just place empty index.php in that directory or create .htaccess with `Options -Indexes` or `Deny from All` there (in includes/).

Comment: no no, this is the question: how to redirect requests which star with "/indules" to "erors/403.html"

Comment: Try sth like:
RewriteRule ^/includes/.*$ - [F,L]
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html

Comment: but your code works when a 403 error occur, if there is an error, your code will work correctly. but there is no error with my users request